# How to switch back from blocking scheduler to previous scheduler using netty-reactor?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

How to switch back from blocking scheduler (blocking-pool) to previous scheduler (reactor-http-nio) using Spring Webflux + Netty + Reactor?

The code:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class BookService {

    private final IBookRepo bookRepo;

    private final BlockingPoolConfig blockingPoolConfig;

    public Mono<Optional<Book>> getBook(Long id) {
        log.debug("getBook() - id: {}", id);
        return asyncCallable(() -> {
            log.trace("getBook() - invoking bookRepo.findById(id) ...");
            return bookRepo.findById(id);
        });
    }

    protected <S> Mono<S> asyncCallable(Callable<S> callable) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(callable)
                .subscribeOn(blockingPoolConfig.blockingScheduler()); 
    }
}

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BookController {

    private final BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping("/book/{id}")
    public Mono<Book> get(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("get() - id: {}", id);
        return bookService.getBook(id)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())  //publishOn(... ?)
                .map(optionalBook -> {
                    return optionalBook.map(book -> {
                        log.debug("get() result: {}", book);
                        return book;
                    }).orElseThrow(() -> {
                        log.debug("book with id: {} is not found.", id);
                        return new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Book not found");
                    });
                });
    }

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class BlockingPoolConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize:8}")
    private int connectionPoolSize = 1;

    @Scope("singleton")
    @Bean
    public Scheduler blockingScheduler() {
        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(connectionPoolSize, connectionPoolSize, "blocking-pool");
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Above i'm using `publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())`, but this one creates new thread pool (parallel). Instead of this I prefer to switch reactor-http-nio thread pool.

Log of actual result:

```
19:17:45.290 [reactor-http-nio-2       ] DEBUG t.a.p.controller.BookController    - get() - id: 1
19:17:45.291 [reactor-http-nio-2       ] DEBUG t.a.p.service.BookService          - getBook() - id: 1
19:17:45.316 [blocking-pool-1          ] TRACE t.a.p.service.BookService          - getBook() - invoking bookRepo.findById(id) ...
19:17:45.427 [parallel-2               ] DEBUG t.a.p.controller.BookController    - get() result: Book(id=1, title=Abc)
```

Log of expected result:

```
19:17:45.290 [reactor-http-nio-2       ] DEBUG t.a.p.controller.BookController    - get() - id: 1
19:17:45.291 [reactor-http-nio-2       ] DEBUG t.a.p.service.BookService          - getBook() - id: 1
19:17:45.316 [blocking-pool-1          ] TRACE t.a.p.service.BookService          - getBook() - invoking bookRepo.findById(id) ...
19:17:45.427 [reactor-http-nio-2       ] DEBUG t.a.p.controller.BookController    - get() result: Book(id=1, title=Abc)
```

Comment: what is BlockingPoolConfig?

Comment: I added source of BlockingPoolConfig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible, because A) these HTTP threads are not controlled by a Reactor `Scheduler`, but by the underlying Netty event loop itself, and B) there's no generic way in Java to "return execution to an (arbitrary) thread" if that thread doesn't have an `Executor`/`ExecutorService` associated with it.

For reactor-netty, once you've switched out of the HTTP threads there should be little reason to want to switch back to the Netty threads anyway. It will be done naturally by reactor-netty once the response is sent.

Assuming blocking pool is something like `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`, you might indeed want to go to `Schedulers.parallel()` to limit the life of the blocking threads, and that's a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: as far as I understand ```Schedulers.parallel()``` is not recommended to use for blocking executions. IBookRepo is spring repository for db interactions.

Comment: sure. but if the blocking part of your process is limited and you have the option to continue the rest of the processing in a non-blocking way, then switching back to parallel() is a good option